# Android: Create correct file name from url

Tags: android, file

I download file from many URLs.

e.g.:

```
https://myhost/sh/8n0wli4v5895jom/AAB2E0WA2fetPTLjWtYe5HjAa/00019.jpg
https://myhost/sh/8n0wli4v5895jom/AAB2E0WA2fetPTLjWtYe5HjAa/0001.jpg
https://myhost2222/sh/8n0wli4v5895jom/AAB2E0WA2fetPTLjWtYe5HjAa/00019.jpg
https://myhost2222/sh/8n0wli4v5895jom/AAB2E0WA2fetPTLjWtYe5HjAa/0001.jpg
```

Now I need to save all download files to Android local folder.

But what is file name must be?
I think to create file name from URL.
But URL contain forbidden characters for file name. So... I thing to create hash (SHA-1) from url or maybe convert URL to Base64.
Is this a good solution?

Comment: What is the forbidden character in the filenames `00019.jpg` and `0001.jpg` that you want to save?

Comment: I update my post. May has another url with same suffix (00019.jpg) and the file will be replaced. But I want to replace files.

Comment: Ok so prior saving, check if the file with this filename already exists, and if yes, add a prefix or suffix to the filename, e.g. `00019-1.jpg` and then save it.

Comment: What kind of prefix/suffix add? I want't to check is exist or not exist. The file name must be always unique.

Comment: anything that suits you best, you can add for example an increment e.g. `-1` so `00019.jpg` will become `00019-1.jpg`

Comment: Example code can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35971399/3635454

Comment: No. Because in my app I has only URL. And by this URL I must get file from local dir (cache). It's will be very difficult if file has prefix/suffix/increment and so on. The file from cache must be get only by URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to save the file with filename the same as the `URL` it was downloaded from. This way it will be easy to find it (reconstruct the filename) in the filesystem (cache) given the `URL`.

So suppose we have this `URL`: `https://myhost/sh/8n0wli4v5895jom/AAB2E0WA2fetPTLjWtYe5HjAa/00019.jpg`

Invalid characters are `:` and `/`, so a simple `String.replaceAll` will remove these characters

```
String filename = "https://myhost/sh/8n0wli4v5895jom/AAB2E0WA2fetPTLjWtYe5HjAa/00019.jpg".replaceAll(":\\/\\/|\\/", "");
```

This `filename` variable equals to: `httpsmyhostsh8n0wli4v5895jomAAB2E0WA2fetPTLjWtYe5HjAa00019.jpg`

Of course if you want you can instead of completely removing those characters, to replace them with a valid character e.g. `-`.

Comment: I create hash (SHA-1) from URL. I'm not need of reverse. And it's work fine

Answer (score 0):

make names from time:

```
String carTime = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
String fileName=carTime.substring(carTime.length() - 4, carTime.length())+".jpg"
```

Comment: No. Because I download many file acync. So the time may equals.

Answer (score 0):

I think a base64 is good solution if you want a reversed way.

```
URL => FILENAME (encode base64)
FILENAME => URL (decode base64)
```

If you just replace `:` and `\` by nothing you lose information and can't 
retreive the orginal URL from FILENAME

If you use a Hash fonction you lose information too *(and you add a very very very small risk of collision)*

**Maybe today you don't need a reversed solution but tomorrow for debug you don't know ;-)**

*Be carrefull : Filenames have limit length*

**EDIT** :

Another solution is to simply create intermediate directory (replacing only https:// by your local temp folder)

Comment: I create hash (SHA-1) from URL. I'm not need of reverse. And it's work fine